# Using TransferManager for uploading a large number of small sized objects

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a large number of files (~ 1 million) and each of them is around 2KB in size. I am currently using s3Client's `PutObject` method in Java. to upload each of the file to an s3 bucket. But the upload for all the files is taking very long (~ 4-5 hours). I have read about `TransferManager` and know that it can be used to upload large sized objects using `multipart`. But this is for files that are atleast 5MB in size which does not satisfy my use case. Is there any way I can use TransferManager to increase the upload speed? If not, what else can I do?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using https requests to upload your file, you can try using multiple prefixes, also you can have multiple replicas of the application so that load can be divided and time will decrease. Other solution is if you are not intending to read individual file in future, you can zip the data in multiple part and upload. You can refer aws docs also.
[aws s3 performance optimization](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/optimizing-performance.html)

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on the first approach?

Comment: The idea here is to have multiple prefixes i.e sub folders so that https requests can be maximized as  mentioned in the shared link.You can use those prefixes(sub foldername) as follows: `s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, "newFolder/"+fileName, file));` Here "newFolder/" specifies a prefix so the file will be put inside the folder named newFolder.